# overflow with expanding listView, and wrong displacement in stack inside column

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a list that when expanded hides under button (stack will do it) and place the button at the bottom of the screen. The problem is whenever the list comes to the bottom edge, it throws an overflow error. The second problem  is that when I wrap list and button in stack, they are stacked on each other. Without stack wrapping the Column the layout is fine but the list still overflows. With stack, the displacement is wrong and app throws vertical overflow error.

I'm aiming towards a layout shown on this picture
[image: layout goal]

**Layout without usage of stack**

[image: layout without usage of stack] \

**Layout with usage of stack**

[image: layout with usage of stack]

Here is task_list_screen.dart:

```
class TaskListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    child: Text(
                      'Your tasks chief',
                      style: GoogleFonts.notoSans(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 500,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          _taskList(),
                          Align(
                            child: _AddTaskButton(),
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add ` _taskList(),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to archive your layout using `floatingActionButton`

**Result**

[image]

**Demo widget**

```
class TaskListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    child: Text(
                      'Your tasks chief',
                      // style: GoogleFonts.notoSans(
                      //     textStyle: TextStyle(
                      //         fontSize: 30,
                      //         fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      // color: Colors.black)),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      ...List.generate(
                        20,
                        (index) => Container(
                          height: 100,
                          color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.pink,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Align(
     ///   alignment: Alignment(0, .95), more controll on dy
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("asda"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```